# Bigquery, how to Multiple-fact, Multiple-grain Query on Conformed Dimensions

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have three fact tables

Budget   : Category, Commodity , Budget Hours

Actual   :Category, Commodity , date, Actual Hours

Baseline :Category, Commodity , date, Forecast hours

I want to write a query to return the sum of budget hours, Actual hours, Forecast hours grouped by category and commodity filtered by date.

please notice the three facts have different level of details, I removed the other uncommon dimension for simplicity
currently I am using this query in Datastudio from BigQuery

```
with t0 as ( select category, commodity FROM `testing-bi-engine.starschema.budget`
             union distinct
             select category, commodity FROM `testing-bi-engine.starschema.actual`
             union distinct
             select category, commodity FROM `testing-bi-engine.starschema.baseline`)
SELECT t0.category, t0.commodity , sum(t2.actualhours) as actualhours , sum(t3.budgethours) as budgethours , sum(t4.forecast) as forecasthours FROM t0
left outer join
(SELECT category, commodity , sum(actualhours) as actualhours FROM `testing-bi-engine.starschema.actual`
WHERE date <= PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)
group by category, commodity) t2
on t0.category= t2.category and t0.commodity= t2.commodity
left outer join
(SELECT category, commodity , sum(budgethours) as budgethours FROM `testing-bi-engine.starschema.budget`
group by category, commodity) t3
on t0.category= t3.category and t0.commodity= t3.commodity
left outer join
(SELECT category, commodity , sum(forecast) as forecast FROM `testing-bi-engine.starschema.baseline`
  WHERE date <= PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)
group by category, commodity) t4
on t0.category= t4.category and t0.commodity= t4.commodity
group by t0.category, t0.commodity
```

it is a typical star schema with multiple fact table
[image]

my question is there a better way to write this query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a better way to write this query ?

Try below:

> Refactoring - Round 1

*Removed unnecessary (most outer) `GROUP BY` with `SUM`s and replaced verbose `ON` to more compact `USING`*

```
#standardSQL
WITH t0 AS ( 
  SELECT category, commodity FROM `testing-bi-engine.starschema.budget` UNION DISTINCT
  SELECT category, commodity FROM `testing-bi-engine.starschema.actual` UNION DISTINCT
  SELECT category, commodity FROM `testing-bi-engine.starschema.baseline`
)
SELECT category, commodity, 
  actualhours , 
  budgethours , 
  forecast 
FROM t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT category, commodity , SUM(actualhours) AS actualhours 
  FROM `testing-bi-engine.starschema.actual`
  WHERE date <= PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)
  GROUP BY category, commodity
) t2 USING(category, commodity)
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT category, commodity , SUM(budgethours) AS budgethours 
  FROM `testing-bi-engine.starschema.budget`
  GROUP BY category, commodity
) t3 USING(category, commodity)
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT category, commodity , SUM(forecast) AS forecast 
  FROM `testing-bi-engine.starschema.baseline`
  WHERE date <= PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)
  GROUP BY category, commodity
) t4 USING(category, commodity)
```

> Refactoring - Round 2

*Eliminated t0 as it is not really needed, thus replacing `LEFT OUTER` to `FULL OUTER`*

```
#standardSQL
SELECT category, commodity, 
  actualhours , 
  budgethours , 
  forecast 
FROM (
  SELECT category, commodity , SUM(actualhours) AS actualhours 
  FROM `testing-bi-engine.starschema.actual`
  WHERE date <= PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)
  GROUP BY category, commodity
) t2 
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT category, commodity , SUM(budgethours) AS budgethours 
  FROM `testing-bi-engine.starschema.budget`
  GROUP BY category, commodity
) t3 USING(category, commodity)
FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT category, commodity , SUM(forecast) AS forecast 
  FROM `testing-bi-engine.starschema.baseline`
  WHERE date <= PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)
  GROUP BY category, commodity
) t4 USING(category, commodity)
```

Comment: would you mind explaining what you did, and if my original query is not optimized ?

Comment: sure. updated my answer with comments on what was done

Comment: sorry, I don't use much SQL, in the first #standardSQL
SELECT category, commodity, 
 how to SQL get me the distinct values of category and commodity as the values are not always the same ?

Comment: because all joined parts have already distinct'ed by category, commodity. So you dont need to distinct already distinct'ed output